# What are the generators of the coset of SU(2)/U(1)?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I need to understand the coset, $SU(2)/U(1)$ for the fundamental representation. How would I go about doing so?

From my understanding of coset it means that any transformation of $SU(2)$ mod a $U(1) $ are equivalent. In other words any transformation related by,
$$
e^{i\phi } e ^{i \frac{1}{2}\sigma^a \alpha^a} = e ^ {i \frac{1}{2}\sigma^a \alpha^a}
$$
is equivalent. But since no linear combination of Pauli matrices forms the identity (in other words $U(1) $ is not a normal subgroup of $SU(2)$) I can't just eliminate one of the generators in this way. How would I go about getting the generators for this group?

Note: I am a physicist with little formal mathematics training so I would prefer an informal explanation.

Comment: In which sense is $U(1)$ a (normal) subgroup of $SU(2)$? You write later that it is not.. so I'm  confused.

Comment: @PeterFranek: I didn't think $U(1)$ was a normal subgroup of $SU(2)$ since it can't be factored out of the group?  Is that a requirement to form a coset?

Comment: Since $U(1)$ is not a normal subgroup, $SU(2)/U(1)$ isn't a group.

Comment: Jeff, not sure what you mean by "factoring out"... but anyway, $U(1)$ is not even a subgroup and $SU(2)$ even don't doesn't contain  a subgroup isomorphic to $U(1)$ so I don't see what you mean.. Unfortunately, I have not enough background in physics. Maybe the problem comes from some confusion in representation theory: do you concider real or complex representation? Not sure if this is helpfull...

Comment: @PeterFranek and AlexG. Thanks for the feedback. It was very helpful. Upon further investigation I realized the symmetry I had was $U(2)$ and so there is no issue with undefined coset groups.

Comment: @PeterFranek Of course $U(1)$ is canonically a subgroup of $SU(2)$ under the identification $e^{i\phi} \mapsto \left(\begin{array}{cc} e^{i\phi} & 0\\0 & e^{-i\phi}\end{array}\right)$

Comment: Oh, of course (sorry for the nonsense).